# Change only datatable column name in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I know how to change a column name in a datatable. I am asking how to change the displayed (as in the `DataGrid`) name only. I refer back to the datatable for user clicks, so the column names need to stay for SQL interaction. I only want to change the name displayed in a WPF form `DataGrid`.

Right now I have:

```
SomeSQLiteDataAdapter.Fill(SomeDataTable);
SomeDataGrid.ItemSource = SomeDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Do I need to make a duplicate datatable for display only, and change them there?

edit:

Thanks @Mark! I ended up with this:

```
void MainDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
switch(e.column.header.ToString())
{
  case "ColumnName1":
  {
  e.header = "NewName1";
  break;
  }
  case "ColumnName2":
  {
  e.header = "NewName2";
  break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are auto-generating the columns for the DataGrid, since if you aren't, all you have to do is set the `.Header` property when you add an explicit column to the grid.

For auto-generated columns, hook the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event, which fires after all of the columns for the grid are auto-generated:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="149" Width="262" AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColunns"/>
```

Then, in the event handler, set the column name to the one that you want:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColunns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (dataGrid.Columns.Count > 0)
  {
    dataGrid.Columns.Where(a => a.Header.ToString() == "query column name").First().Header = "desired display name";
  }
}
```

The zero count check is needed because the event fires every time the grid auto generates the columns, which may sometimes be zero columns.

Comment: Does this allow me to check the "selected" column by name in the datatable, not the header?

Comment: Yes, you can use (usually) the `SortMemberPath` property since you have a bound data source, or since the columns are bound columns, you can use the `.Binding.Path` sub-property to get the query column name.